# How to display Mysql database data in a table ( jsp)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans

I want to display database results in a Webpage Using JSP.

I have followed various tutorialas and it seems that the code itself isn't wrong, but when I run the Java WebApp,the webpage shows a blank table with only the titles.

I wish to know if there is something wrong with my code, mainly if my I am displaying the results from the results sets in the table properly

I've run the java part on a java class and the Database connection works fine, if I output the result set it shows the data on the database

```
<table border="2" align="center" > 

 <tr>
 <th>NIT Planta</th>
 <th>Direccion</th>
 <th>Proceso</th>
 </tr>

 <%
    Connection cnx=null;
    Statement sta=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try
    {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     cnx=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresamoda","root","123456");

     sta=cnx.createStatement();
     rs=sta.executeQuery("SELECT Pdp.NIT_Planta,Pdp.DireccionPlanta,Pdpro.DescripcionProceso "
           + "                FROM Planta_de_produccion Pdp INNER JOIN Proceso_de_Produccion Pdpro "
           + "                ON Pdp.ID_Planta=Pdpro.ID_Planta");
    while(rs.next()){
       %>
       <tr>
           <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
           <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
           <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
       </tr>


       <%
    }
    sta.close();
    rs.close();
    cnx.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

     }
 %>

</table>
```

I expect to see the results in the result set on a table in a webpage, not just a blank table.

Comment: **First**, are you sure your query returns any result? I.e. did you test it in DB directly, e.g. in mysql command line client? **Second**, put at least `e.printStackTrace();` into the `catch` block to see there is no error. (Anyone who leaves the `catch` block empty should be flogged, IMHO.)

Comment: Regarding the first question, it does, I put the query and it works. I will try to do the e.printStackTracer into the catch block. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, just tried the  e.printStackTrace();  and it doesn't show any errors whatsoever, but it the table still appears empty when running the .jsp file